# Issue with loading script tag in Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm facing issue with script in `Joomla 3.3.6`. I have script which loads ads

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  ( function() {
    if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
    var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"publisher","width":728,"height":90,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
    var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
    window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
    document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
}());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async></script>
```

On page loading it will show like:

```
'); }());
```

I have removed `Joomla` editor filtering and script is storing in DB properly.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  ( function() {
    if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
    var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"publisher","width":728,"height":90,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
    var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
    window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
    document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"/>');
}());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async></script>
```

`Div` tag closing was giving error

```
document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"/>');
```

instead of

```
document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ( function() {
    if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
      var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"publisher","width":728,"height":90,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
      var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
      window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
      document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
})();
```

use this. you made a mistake in **}());**. changed     **})();**

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. Also this error was because of  document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"/>')